# Filesystem is readonly from container

Tags: docker

I'm using Bamboo as a CI solution which hosts a docker environment (DIND).

It runs a docker container as such:

```
/usr/bin/docker run 
--volume /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1 

--volume /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp 

--detach 

--net=host
 
-name 0c6c0665-e388-46eb-a379-19a52289b4942621443 internals/terraform:0.13.5 
tail -f /dev/null
```

However, when it runs a script inside the container, on the path `/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1`, the operation fails stating that the filesystem is readonly. Doing the operation from the Bamboo runner (in Kubernetes) and the file system isn't read-only.

Permissions of the RO directory:`drwxr-xr-x`

Mount shows the following:

```
10.24.71.11:zpool-127609/data/conductor/agents/0 on /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.24.71.11,mountvers=3,mountport=34755,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.24.71.11)
```

Output of `docker inspect`

```
$ docker inspect 26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f
[
    {
        "Id": "26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f",
        "Created": "2020-12-20T15:37:35.25732282Z",
        "Path": "tail",
        "Args": [
            "-f",
            "/dev/null"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 352,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-12-20T15:37:36.622954493Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:2a709b31dd875f77cea0c605b7175157d33fe274d532dd1b3c539f1be4659d7b",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f/26fbb042f8aeaa047e4bd4b0d0dec5b3520437ea899ebc3e0d8646737aea032f-json.log",
        "Name": "/0c6c0665-e388-46eb-a379-19a52289b4942621443",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp",
                "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6247c08730bf6dfb7634c22d6650da79a941c6c6a2ad4e9c991feef19b2ab419-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f7ef8ae82689487bb85524d1bbd5fd0b1f526af1d0c3d718f4b7ec72a0f143f8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/278687b3bc49308491343d07768291489402b3ff490d17c397143a143e45f42c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/43946435acfcba389353825c00e86c37a0d606b828ca64004a6d1a108b34bbbd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/891133274fba0c06b2c58ab8f801f673a25ae41113de2acd4e8c9a2f21ebd447/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6247c08730bf6dfb7634c22d6650da79a941c6c6a2ad4e9c991feef19b2ab419/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6247c08730bf6dfb7634c22d6650da79a941c6c6a2ad4e9c991feef19b2ab419/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6247c08730bf6dfb7634c22d6650da79a941c6c6a2ad4e9c991feef19b2ab419/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1",
                "Destination": "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp",
                "Destination": "/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "kubernetes-agent-pfr8v",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "tail",
                "-f",
                "/dev/null"
            ],
            "Image": "internals/terraform:0.13.5",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.hashicorp.terraform.version": "0.13.5"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "098b24e38ccc775cef09cab73f189c92ac489fc031e7f4defd02d17e15e43e3d",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "824095738e152e8b2da3ef5e2e958ca70881672f8e2e9eb8d7c52f587b63353c",
                    "EndpointID": "3c2d497790b255b4c0ea9af0ac836e64a5e2406576e4f4788ff04ff23efeab0c",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Can someone think of my it's coming up as read-only?

Comment: How are the permissions of the mounted directories?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: And the owner and group? Does it match the user inside the container? (Usually 1000)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it's showing up as bamboo:bamboo, which is the default for that container (USER bamboo)

Comment: The username is irrelevant. Does the numerical user id from the container (usually 1000) match the numerical owner id of the directory on the host (`ln -ln`)?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes it's 1000:1000, and matches that on the directory of the host.

Comment: Can you share the output of `docker inspect` for that container?

Comment: added @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 0):

This behavior looks like the one I faced. Please check https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-20951